# Determine Which Main Effect Belongs to Which Interaction

Tags: r, interaction

Assume we have the following model:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(a = gl(4, 1, 64), a4 = sample(4, 64, TRUE), 
                x = rnorm(64), y = rnorm(64))

l <- lm(y ~ a4 + a * x, d)
```

For the interaction `x:a` I will get 3 coefficients `x:a2, x:a3, x:a4`. I want now to determine which coefficients are the corresponding main effects associated to this interactions, which would be `x, a2, a3` and `a4`.

My idea was to use `strsplit` on the interactions and to retrieve the corresponding main effects:

```
(atoms <- strsplit(names(coef(l))[7:9], ":"))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a2" "x" 
# [[2]]
# [1] "a3" "x" 
# [[3]]
# [1] "a4" "x"
```

So far so good. But now I would like to get the value of the corresponding main effect. While this is straight forward for `x, a2, a3` (as these are unique names) I struggle to see how I can do that with `a4`:

```
lapply(atoms, function(.) coef(l)[.])
# [[1]]
#        a2         x 
# 0.3630732 0.2136751 
# [[2]]
#         a3          x 
# 0.04153299 0.21367510 
# [[3]]
#         a4          x 
# 0.04765737 0.21367510
```

The result for `a4` is wrong, because it is the main effect associated with the variable `a4` and not the dummy coded factor `4` of factor `a`.

So, the model I was showing is a valid model in R, yet the names of the coefficients are ambiguous. So is there any other way how I can make a correct mapping between the coefficients of an interaction and the corresponding main effects?

Comment: Why not just rename the column `a4` beforehand? `names(d)[which(names(d)=="a4")] <- "a4_"`.

Comment: Or taking the last `a4` of all `a4`s: `lapply(atoms, function(x) coef(l)[!duplicated(names(coef(l)), fromLast = T)][x])` .

Comment: Well, this does not really solve the problem in a sustainable way, as it depends on the order of the parameters in the model (over which I do not have control). I could refit the model to ensure unique names, but this seems to me like an overkill. Is the only way to make the connection via the names of the effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `assign` component of the `lm` object:

```
l$assign
[1] 0 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4
```

This maps the coefficients to the expanded formula `a4 + a + x + a:x`.

See `help("model.matrix")` for documentation of the `assign` component.

**Edit:**

To expand my answer, you can do this:

```
terms <- labels(terms(l))
coef(l)[l$assign %in% which(terms %in% strsplit("a:x", ":", fixed = TRUE)[[1]])]

#        a2         a3         a4          x 
#0.36307321 0.04153299 0.23383125 0.21367510
```

Comment: Yes, I know this slot, but how does it help to identify the corresponding main effects? I can use `assign` to identify that coefficients `3:5` belong to `a` but how do I identify the corresponding main effects?

Comment: WOW! You did it - thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for!